# How to show default images when no item in Gridview?

Tags: android, gridview

I am using custom `Gridview` which looks like Shelf. I am showing 3 columns 
When there is 5 items from the server , the 6th position of the `Gridview` is empty

I wanted to show the rack line image in it

Grid_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.andexert.library.RippleView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/ripple_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="90dp"
    android:background="@drawable/im_ninja_delights_rack"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    app:rv_centered="true"
    app:rv_framerate="5"
    app:rv_rippleDuration="50">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_ninja_delights"
        android:layout_width="75dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/chocolates_image"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:visibility="visible"></ImageView>
</com.andexert.library.RippleView>
```

> [image]

im_ninja_delights_rack.png

> [image]

Comment: Why don't you use Piccaso library to set placeholder for your image ?

Comment: You are having only five elements in the grid. You need to populate the multiple of there so the rest item can be created in the grid view with the default image.

Comment: Check your arraylist size  - I think list in 5 item So last one not fillup.. If you are getting arraylist size 6 then checking image url . In Piccaso library onError listener method to handle in your code .In OnErrorListener set your default image

Comment: I am using Glide ... could you pls give me some code example ?

Comment: Plz give me arraylist size first

Answer (score 2):

Use piccaso library to set placeholder for your imageView

like this

```
Picasso.with(this)
.load("IMAGE URL")
.placeholder(R.drawable.default_image) // optional
.error(R.drawable.error_image)         // optional
.into(imageView);
```

Comment: do i need to do anything with Gridview android:stretchMode="columnWidth" ?

Comment: place holder wont work in my case .. because the rack image is a background of root layout . I want this background image to be visible still when no items in column

Answer (score 1):

i was working on same condition use this

## Adapter class

1.

```
public int getCount()
{

    return mItems.size()+1;
}
```

2.

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View gridView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.test_grid_layout, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) gridView.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
            if(position == mItems.size())
            {
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.blank_img);
            }
            else
                {
                imageView.setImageURI(Uri.parse(mItems.get(position)));
            }
            return gridView;
        }
```

[image]

last one is blank images

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to show 3 images per row, Make sure that your image list is multiple of 3.

then, set a default image to the imageviews that you are using in inflated xml.

do something similar to this,

in your activity, call adapter constructor as,

```
    gridView.setAdapter(new BaseAdapterClass(context, actual_data_list, actual_data_list.size() + number_to_make_size_multiple_of_3));
```

then, in your Adapter class,

```
    public int getCount(){
        return multiple_of_3_passed_from_activity;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if(position < actual_data_list.size()) {
            // Set your image to imageview
        }

        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: the rack is a background of root layout of grid_item.xml . I wanted the rack to be stretched

Answer (score -2):

[image: 1]

Did you mean that?

My solution here is adding some fake items to fill out the line with rack and disable onClick for them.